# Stop regex capture at end of the line control string

Tags: regex, eol

Considering the following string, how can I get my REGEX to stop capturing at the first `\r` and capture all chars starting at the `CN=`?

```
CrtDN: CN=user1,OU=place1-sp,O=happy3,O=really\r\n\r\n>
```

Comment: What regex have you got?

Comment: Pretty sure sth. like `CN=[^\r]+`, that is CN, followed by anything not `\r`. You might want to add `\n`, so `CN=[^\r\n]+`.

Comment: Using regex inside of SPLUNK

Answer (score 1):

Many patterns will produce a match. One successful pattern is the following. [See demo here](https://regex101.com/r/pS6aV7/2).

https://regex101.com/r/pS6aV7/2

```
CrtDN:\s(.*?)\\r
```

Answer (score 0):

To match *only* the target, use a look behind with a negated character class:

```
(?<=CN=)[^\r]+
```